# How to add functionality of "Recently visited products" on an ecommerce website?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am working on an e-commerce website (online shopping) which sells various products. I want to show the user a list of products that the user has browsed recently. Can you please help me in achieving this?

I am using PHP, MySQL, Apache HTTP on a Windows server.

Thanks!!

Comment: You could use sessions and save the product IDs of the user: `session_start(); $_SESSION['products'][] = $current_product_id;`

Comment: You need to research the use of session variables in PHP. Alternatively you can store IPs in a database along with a serialized array of product keys, descriptiosn whatever. No one here is going to write your code for you, if you want someone to do that hire a developer. Have a go and ask for help is what we do here.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a database or cookie.  This database method will persist even after users clear their browser cookies:

Create a table in your database something like:

```
userid,
productid,
viewdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Whenever a visitor views a product, you simply insert a row into the database identifying the user, the product, and a timestamp of when it was visited.

```
-- Insert
INSERT INTO recentlyviewed (userid, productid) VALUES (userid, productid);
```

Next time the user loads a page, you retrieve the most recent *n* products they viewed and display them.  Periodically, you can run a scheduled job to clean up view records older than some number of days you've chosen to expire them.

```
-- Cleanup old records after 14 days
DELETE FROM recentlyviewed WHERE viewdate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -14 DAY);
```

Comment: This will work only if we know the user id (i.e.. The logged In user) . How can we get the recently viewed products of the anonymous user who visits and looked up some products and re-visit the store after a week i can show them .

Comment: @Raaga You would store a cookie for the anonymous user that holds a session id or some identifier to the `recentlyviewed` list. Instead of `userid`, the table `recentlyviewed` would have a column for that session id or cookie token.

Comment: It may accumulate the table with large amount of records . How to overcome this . whether i have to clean the table after few days. ?

Comment: @Raaga Clean the table on the same schedule as the cookie expiration. If you cannot support very long term storage of the recently viewed items, expire the cookie after 30 days or 7 days and delete rows from the table on a cron schedule accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways, that I can think of, to do this.

1. You can store which products they've viewed in a cookie.
2. You can store their session_id in a database and then store the viewed products in there related to the session_id.

I think the second option is the better as you can then use this data to create some kind of 'people who viewed this product also view this one' like Amazon have

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, you create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE views(
id bigint not null auto_increment,
user_id bigint not null,
product_id bigint not null,
primary key(id)
)
```

And every time a user views a product, you save the user's id and the product id here. You can then using a simple select query get the latest 10 products a user has viewed,  as well as get the view count for a single product.